# Using Redis BITFIELD as counter with specific bounds

Tags: redis

I am trying to use [BITFIELD](https://redis.io/commands/bitfield/#:%7E:text=Where%20an%20integer%20encoding%20is,signed%20integer%20of%2016%20bits.) as counter in my rate limiter application by defining its lowest and highest bounds but not sure how to achieve it. What exactly I need it is that, counter starts from 0 and can go up to 30 at max (or any other number I need in future such as 10,000).

The one below goes up to 15 and then responds with `null`. Not sure how to specify these limits.

```
BITFIELD k-19 OVERFLOW FAIL INCRBY u4 1 1
```

Note: I can achieve this using a Lua script but I am not sure if it would cause performance issues.

```
local key = KEYS[1]
local inc = ARGV[1]
local max = tonumber(ARGV[2])

local val = redis.call("GET", key) or 0

val = val + inc
if (val >= 0 and val < max) then
    redis.call("SET", key, val)

    return val
end

return max
```

UPDATE:

As per Guy Royse and Lior Kogan's answers, I think BITFIELD may not be the best fit for the purpose for this case. It is mainly because the upper limit won't always be "power of 2 minus 1" or anything close to it in my case.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do better than this. Unless, of course, you can change `max` from 30 to 31 (or any other 2^*n*-1 where *n* is an integer value). If so, you can simply assign *n* bits and set `OVERFLOW` to `SAT`.

One note about your code: `val = val + inc` may be sensitive to loss of integral precision, but it is not a real issue if you control these values.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I think `2^n-1` rule just makes what I am trying to do redundant. One question though. What did you mean by "sensitive to lost of integral precision" in the second sentence please? Should I run a check or something like that before moving on to the `if` statement or something else?

Comment: Lua numbers are stored as floating point (doubles) internally, not integers; thus while they can represent incredibly large numbers, above 2^53 they lose integral precision — they can’t represent every whole integer value. For example if you set a lua variable to the number 9007199254740992 and tried to increment it by 1, you’d get the same number because it can’t represent 9007199254740993 (only the even number 9007199254740994).
Source: https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsdg_html_chunked/lua_module_Int64.html

Comment: Got it. I think it is fair to say that I am safe here because the `val` will never ever get anywhere near in64. It is allowed to be max between 120 and 240.

Answer (score 1):

The command you are issuing says to increment the 4-bit unsigned integer located at position 1 (i.e the second position as BITFIELD is zero-based) by a value of 1. If this 4-bit number—which as a 4-bit number can only have values between 0 and 15—overflows (i.e exceeds the maximum value of a 4-bit number), then error by returning null and do not increment the value.

This is just how it works. There is no way to set an upper or lower bound that isn't a power of 2 minus 1 as these are binary numbers. You could use a unsigned 5-bit number and then the upper bound would be 31. Or a 6-bit number and then we're at 63.

However, I think you might be overthinking this. I would just use [INCR](https://redis.io/commands/incr/) and [DECR](https://redis.io/commands/decr/) for this instead. Both return the new value of the key. Both are atomic. And internally, Redis stores numbers in Strings as integers so it's not even taking up more space.

It would look like this:

```bash
127.0.0.1:6379> INCR foo
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> INCR foo
(integer) 2
127.0.0.1:6379> INCR foo
(integer) 3
127.0.0.1:6379> DECR foo
(integer) 2
127.0.0.1:6379> DECR foo
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> INCR foo
(integer) 2
```

And to show that it is indeed a number and not a string:

```bash
127.0.0.1:6379> GET foo
"2"
127.0.0.1:6379> OBJECT ENCODING foo
"int"
127.0.0.1:6379> SET foo bar
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> OBJECT ENCODING foo
"embstr"
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation and the suggestion. Much appreciated. I have users concurrently access the API so I will have to WATCH keys and run commands accordingly to return right counter values back otherwise I will end up allowing requests more than allowed. I'll see what I can do.